# How to add dynamic table value

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have one html in which I am displaying value like this.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header"></tr> 
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>France</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want table to dependent on json value. so for that I am writing below function but don't know why not getting luck.I want to add these JSON value into my table. table should be dynamic. Also url is also dynamic.

```
function foo(myURL,callback) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', myURL,true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                // trigger your callback function
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    foo(function(data) {
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt="";
        for(i=0;i<jsonc.length;i++)
        {
            new_opt+='<td>'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'</td>';
        }
        document.getElementById('choose').innerHTML =new_opt;
    });
```

My JSON

```
[
    {
        "ID" : 0,
        "VALUE" : "United State"
    },{
        "ID"  : 1,
        "VALUE" : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        "ID"  : 2,
        "VALUE" : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        "ID"  : 3,
        "VALUE" : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        "ID"  : 4,
        "VALUE" : "Albania"
    }
]
```

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo, but you're calling `foo` without url.

Comment: i don't see any element with id="choose" !!

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene "choose" is the div is inside table is placed :)

Comment: @NathanP. In second foo you mena ?

Comment: @David Yep. Also, you should get the `table`, not the parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get your JSON value, Then could do this,

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$("#myTable tbody tr").remove();
makeTableFromJson(obj);
```

> function makeTableFromJson(data)

```
function makeTableFromJson(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    var td = $("<td>");
    td.append(i + 1);
    var td0 = $("<td>");
    td0.append(data[i]['jsonVal']);
    var td1 = $("<td>");
    td1.append(data[i]['jsonVal']);
    var td2 = $("<td>");
    td2.append(data[i]['jsonVal']);
    var td3 = $("<td>");
    td3.append(data[i]['jsonVal']);
    var td4 = $("<td>");

    tr.append(td);
    tr.append(td0);
    tr.append(td1);
    tr.append(td2);
    tr.append(td3);
    tr.append(td4);

    $("#myTable tbody").append(tr);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intent on using jQuery, you can do it the following way :

```
function foo(str) {
    var array = JSON.parse(str);
    $.each(array,function(i,obj){
        var $tr = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(obj.VALUE)).attr("id", obj.ID);
        $("#myTable > tbody").append($tr);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like, i just tried to create the your situation. Hope it will help.

```js
var data = [{
        "ID" : 0,
        "VALUE" : "United State"
    },{
        "ID"  : 1,
        "VALUE" : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        "ID"  : 2,
        "VALUE" : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        "ID"  : 3,
        "VALUE" : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        "ID"  : 4,
        "VALUE" : "Albania"
    }
];
foo(data);

function foo (data)
{
    
        var new_opt="";
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            new_opt+='<tr><td>'+data[i]['VALUE']+'</td></tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById('choose').innerHTML = new_opt;
}
```

```html
<table id="choose">
  <tr class="header" ></tr> 
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>France</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
foo(function(data){
 var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.border = "1";
 
   
 
    //Add the header row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Countries";
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  
 
    //Add the data rows. 
    for (var i = 1; i < jsonc.length; i++) {
             row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = jsonc[i]['VALUE'];
    }
 
    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);

});
```

```html
<div id="dvTable">
</div>
```